# Thunderbird composing: copy+paste image between text lines

Tags: email, thunderbird, attachment

I want to write a mail with this layout:

> first line
>
> IMAGE
>
> second line

I tried these things:

- In nautilus right-click on the image, then **copy**. Then **paste** in thunderbird: The path name gets inserted: `/home/me/tmp/foo.png`. That's not what I want.
- I click on a image in a web-page with right-click **copy image**. Then paste in thunderbird: The icon for broken images gets inserted. Again, not what I want.

I feel stupid. How to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through the user menus at the top of the app with Thunderbird:

1. Create a new message in Mozilla Thunderbird.
2. Put the cursor where you want the image to appear in the body of the email.
3. Select <kbd>Insert</kbd>-<kbd>Image</kbd> from the menu.
4. Use the <kbd>Choose File...</kbd> selector to locate and open the desired graphic.
5. Type a short textual description of the image under Alternate text if needed.
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
7. Continue editing your message.

[Source](https://www.lifewire.com/insert-inline-image-thunderbird-1173116)

Comment: **Tatsu** Please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1106597/revisions) and the [editing help](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing) to improve the readability of your answers in the future.  (Also: **+1**)  **;-)**

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It explains a work-around. Inser-Image does work. It would be fantastic if copy+paste would work, too.

Answer (score 0):

It also works with drag and drop. Just arrange your message window and the nautilus window so that you see both of them. Then grab the picture's file name and drag it into the message at the place you want to insert it. It will show up in the original size (resizable with the usual handles).